# Cin is working for char array but not for int array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I'm using `cin` for taking input for a char array.

```
char mycroft[2];
    cin>>mycroft;
    cout<<mycroft;
```

It works fine. Now I'm using `cin` for taking input for an int array:

```
 int mycroft[2];
    cin>>mycroft;
    cout<<mycroft;
```

However, I am getting this error which I do not understand:

> error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' and 'int [2]')|

Can someone please tell me why it's not working? Also my professor said taking input using `cin` isn't advisable. To what extent is that true?

Comment: That's because a `char` array is treated as an old C-style *string*. There are no such special handling for any other array or pointer. This of course means that for your example character array only can input a single character.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude umm...no? i've given "HELLO" as a word and it worked!

Comment: Then the input operator will write six characters (don't forget the string terminator) to a two-element array. It will write out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*. That's why you should always use `std::string` for string input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood the concept of `char` arrays and `int` (and others) arrays.

When you create a `char variable[x]` you reserve space in memory to `x * 8` bits (length of `char`) and the language treat it like a continuous space.
To finish this chain you need to put the end character `'\0'`.
The `char mycroft[2]` has 1 usable `char` (in theory) with 16 bits (2 * 8 bits) space in memory.

In the other hand, when you create an `int variable[x]` you reserve space in memory to `x * 32` bit (length of `int`) and despite the system allocate it continuously, the language treat every `x` elements individually.
In short, treat it like a real array.
The `int mycroft[2]` has 2 usable elements and takes 64 bits (2 * 32 bits) space in memory.

Because of that `cin` works with `char` directly (`cin >> mycroft` and `cout << mycroft`) and doesn't work and with the other arrays (in your case `int`) you need to access them individually (`cin >> mycroft[position]` and `cout << mycroft[position]`).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++) 
{
   cin>>mycroft[i];
 ...
}
```

Comment: ummm..that's simplest approach..ik it..but the way how I took it is takes less time in competitive coding...I think i'm looking for a way to make that way work with int array

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @Mark Learn to code. Then learn to compete. Doing it the other way around typically teaches you to write really, really bad code. For example, in the name of coding speed, you're wasting time on the impossible.

Comment: @user4581301 I couldn't agree more..but sometimes a way does exist!! I just wanna know that..

Comment: @Mark `iostream`s chain. for example `cin>>mycroft[0]>>mycroft[1];` [or write a `>>` overload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) that performs the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because an array of characters can means it's a C-style string (if zero-terminated, i.e. the last element in the array is zero). The `std::cout` and the `std::cin` treat them in such way.

A `char[]` can be initialized as:

```
char mycroft[] = "Hello, World!";
```

An `int[]` can't be initialized in such way, it's an array of integers. The reason why your professor told you that taking input using `std::cin` isn't advisable is that it can cause overflows if you using it in a wrong way. In your first example the `std::cin` will write everything from the input into a two element long array causing the memory follows the `char mycroft[2]` will be overwritten.